# travis-ci setup releases with --github-token

Tags: github, travis-ci

I am having problems using setup releases with a github token. I like travis-ci but I am not willing to hand out my github password - I need to use the token and I read the documentation as this should be possible this way. Unfortunately it still asks for pasword:

```
$ travis login --github-token XXXXXXXXX
Successfully logged in as ligi!

$ travis whoami 
You are ligi (ligi)

$ travis setup releases
Detected repository as ligi/gobandroid, is this correct? |yes| 
Username:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Travis CI CLI will not send the GitHub password to Travis CI, instead it will send it to GitHub and use it to generate a GitHub token (the same is true for `travis login`).

However, if you still feel uncomfortable, you can configure the deployment manually.

Add the following to your .travis.yml:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key: "GITHUB OAUTH TOKEN"
  file: "FILE TO UPLOAD"
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
```

You can encrypt the GitHub OAuth token via `travis encrypt ...`. It is not necessary to be logged in via the CLI for this, and the encryption happens locally.

See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/ for the full documentation

Comment: This is also potentially dangerous. This way you're be typing your password (in plaintext) into a terminal command, which is probably going to be stored in a log somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a route which doesn't involve typing your GitHub password into the terminal. I assume you have the travis CI installed. This assumes you're using `travis-ci.org`, but replacing `--org` with `--com` should work otherwise.

If `github.com/your/repo` was your repo:

1. Generate a [Github personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) with the following scope: `read:org, public_repo, repo:status, repo_deployment, user:email, write:repo_hook`
2. (Optional?) Login using `travis login <github token> --org`
3. Run `echo <github token> | travis encrypt --org -r your/repo`
4. Use that secret in your `.travis.yml` file as described in the documentation

You may need to provide full repo scope, but for the free tier of Travis, `public_repo` is enough. I'm also not sure which of the other scopes are mandatory.

`echo` is useful on Windows because Ctrl-D doesn't work properly in Powershell.

Comment: What "key" is the one you refer to in step 3, `<your key>`?

Comment: Extremely helpful when the travis CLI hangs too (running in git bash on Win 10).  The `<your key>` is the key that the GitHub UI gives you after performing step 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `-t`/`--token` option, e.g.

```
travis login --org --github-token G1tHu8T0K3N
travis setup releases --org -t G1tHu8T0K3N
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. When I do that I get a successful login with the first command and then an error saying I'm not logged in when I run the second.