# Travis - Android Project deploy failed on Github

Tags: android, travis-ci

I want to use Travis for my semester project and I have a problem, I can't deploy on my releases on Git
Someone got an idea ?

Here my Travis link https://travis-ci.org/JulienHivert/ptut_Ol-d_Tam/jobs/386631017 & my .travis.yml

```
    language: android
    jdk: oraclejdk8
    android:
     components:
     - tools
     - platform-tools
     - build-tools-27.0.3
     - android-27
     - extra-google-m2repository
     - extra-android-m2repository

    before_script:
    - chmod 755 ./gradlew
    - chmod 755 ./build-apk.sh

    script:
    - ./gradlew testDebugUnittest
    - ./build-apk.sh

    deploy:
      provider: releases
      api_key:
        secure: "a09cee7c290b9674086333ba6baabdde105e31ab"
      file: "./build/apk/juxebox.apk"
      file_glob: true
      skip_cleannup : true
      on:
        repo: JulienHivert/ptut_Ol-d_Tam
        branch: master
```

Comment: IMHO, the error message is comprehensive enough `GET https://api.github.com/user: 401 - Bad credentials // See: https://developer.github.com/v3 (Octokit::Unauthorized)`

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: The api_key doesn't seem to be right. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57032190/7098025